# Setting Up Sharepoint Apps On Premises Sharepoint 2016

Tags: 2016

I already followed all steps from this url:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx

And I can install already APPS, and the ICON is shown fine on the site contents page.

However when I clic on it; i get a 404 error

http://app-7a42bbc34f04f4.myappsdomain.com/YoutubeFeedsApp/_layouts/15/authenticate.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fapp-7a42bbc34f04f4%2Evirtualuco%2Ecom%2FYoutubeFeedsApp%2FPages%2FDefault%2Easpx%3FSPHostUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww%252Euco%252Eedu%252Eco%26SPLanguage%3Des%252DES%26SPClientTag%3D16%26SPProductNumber%3D16%252E0%252E4327%252E1000%26SPAppWebUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fapp%252D7a42bbc34f04f4%252Evirtualuco%252Ecom%252FYoutubeFeedsApp

The Forward loookup zone and the wildcard cname is already done.

1. Do I need to make any manual step in IIS?, what about if I have 2 Front Ends with load balancer?

Thank you

Comment: There's a Pluralsight course that covers how to configure SharePoint for Apps. The course is for SharePoint 2013 but the steps will be the same for SharePoint 2016. As an MVP you can get a free Pluralsight subscription if you don't already have one. https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/configuring-sharepoint-2013-for-apps/table-of-contents

Comment: yes I already have the subscription, I will take a look at it to see what am I missing.